# Problem after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, 16.04

I run HP laptop Pavilion with processor S7 and Intel Graphic card hd 520. 
Just bought this laptop about 3 months ago.

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 and rebooting, I got flashing screen between graphic mode and text continually.

After reading some of the answers I logged through command line and attempted to execute command which some suggested solve their problem.

They said do this.

```
sudo apt get-update (enter password when prompted) 
sudo apt get-install xserver-xorg-video-intel
reboot
```

After typing first line I got another problem.

```
relocation error relocation error /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0: symbol ZNK.....   in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

Any suggestion? Be gentle with me, this is my first computer with Ubuntu.

As a note, when I run installation to try out without installing from the CD for 16.04 I get into desktop, no problems with drivers.
I have option to install fresh install but this would cause me a lot of work to recreate what I had already and it is possible that I would be faced with the same problem after that.

Comment: Are you by any chance using AMD's RADEON graphics ? Those seems to have driver issues in 16.04. Or in simple words, driver not ready yet.

Comment: No this **Intel Graphic card hd 520**. I can run Ubuntu 6.04 as trying only from the CD with no problems. Would this not suggest that graphic card is supported?

Comment: Upgrading was probably a mistake. If not solved yet, I recommend switching to Windows, the time you'll waste on this and similar things might not be worth it.

Comment: I did reinstall and no major issues so far.